# Ask the proof: $f$ of $X$ into $Y$ is continuous if and only if $f$ is continuous at every point of $X$?

Tags: general-topology

From Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis 1.5 Proposition: Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. A mapping $f$ of $X$ into $Y$ is continuous if and only if $f$ is continuous at every point of $X$.

I don't understand the proof.

**Proof** (1st paragraph): If $f$ is continuous and $x_0 \in X$, then $f^{-1}(V)$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$ for every neighborhood $V$ of $f(x_0)$. Since $f(f^{-1}(V)) \subset V$, it follows that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

I am confused to understand the above. I think it is repetitive. From this direction, we only know $f$ is continuous, thus how can we guarantee that:" $f^{-1}(V)$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$"?

Now I have a new problem on 2nd paragraph. Proof: If $f$ is continuous at every point of X and if V is open in Y, every point $x \in f^{-1}(V)$ has a neighborhood $W_x$ such that $f(W_x) \subset V$. I am clear until now. but next:

**It follows that $f^{-1}(V)$ is the union of the open sets $W_x$, WHY?**

so $f^{-1}(V)$ is itself open. Thus $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Because, by continuity we know $f^{-1}(V)$ is open and it obviously contains $x_0$.

Comment: Yes, I know by continuity we know $f^{-1}(V)$ is open. But how do we know it must contain $x_0$?

Comment: @Mariana Because $V$ contains $f(x_0)$.

Comment: I have a new problem, thanks.